# TypeScript: Reuse of interfaces and classes for frontend (Angular) and backend

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a monorepo for a current project based on a Frontend (Angular) and a Backend (developed with NestJS - so it's NodeJS). I want to use custom interfaces and classes for both - frontend and backend. For example, creating DTOs so my frontend knows the parameter of my backend.

I thought about a common folder like the following project structure shows, but this is not working, because the common folder is outside the scope of Angular (tsconfig) and so auto completition isn't working

```
project
├── client (Angular)
├── server (NestJS)
└── common (client and server share specific interfaces and classes)
```

Does anyone has experience for this? At the moment I add my interfaces to both folders, but this is is evil because if I update one interface, I have to replace the other, too.

Comment: Try this resource : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-structure-a-large-web-app-project/

Comment: Thanks, but exporting it as tgz file or upload to npm (public or private) to use it external, is not nice. Maybe there is another option without npm

Comment: with angular 6 monorepo support was introduced. you should upgrade to ng6+ and move your interfaces to a ng library. then you should be able to use those in both projects. it is not possible though to put those on the first layer of your folder structure, since it has to be inside the angular scope in order to make it work with angular cli. alternatively you can put them in an npm module of course.

Comment: The server is no Angular project, so this is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tool like [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) helps with this sort of setup, from experience this is the easiest way to go about things without creating any private npm repos (which is another alternative).

Essentially, you setup your angular and server packages to install the common package just like any other npm package and run lerna to create virtual links for each package.
This way when you need them for intellisense the editor will go thru the virtual file links lerna creates during the bootstrap phase, thus allowing you to create any number of common packages without doing any heavy lifting to connect all the consumer packages.

Comment: Lerna is at the moment the easiest and (for me the only) working solution

Answer (score 13):

In TypeScript 3.0 "Project references" were introduced. This could help you achieve what you want (I was using it to share models between angular and cloud function)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

What you need to do is add an external project reference to the `tsconfig.json` of the project that should reuse files from somewhere else

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // The usual config
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../my-other-project" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried that few weeks ago, but that wasn't working. I also did not found any project or Github Repository which shows a working example

Comment: Hi, what about this repo? It seems like a useful example https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo

Comment: package.json is missing, so I cannot verify if it works. In my projects auto complete isn't working if I use  project references

Answer (score 4):

In your tsconfig.json add common to `paths` property:

```
     "paths": {
       "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"],
       "rxjs/*": ["node_modules/rxjs/*"],
       "common/*": ["../common/*"]
     }
```

Then:
`import myInterface from 'exported interface in common folder';`

The best is to have an index.ts which exports all services, interfaces whatever:
`export * from './myFile'`

Comment: This is only working LOCAL. if you want to run it on server, it will not work because the aliases aren't resolved (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8138 )